# All Event Delegation to Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, events

Currently I have **350+** events like

`$(document).on('click','.removable-init',function(){});`

Im seeing a performance problem some click events are delayed by fraction of second. 
But my whole site is dynamically generated with ajax.

I want to know how to deal with these kind of problems.

For example of my site's flow lets look below.

**ONLOAD**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="main">
   <button id="clickme"></button>
   <button id="clickme2"></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ON CLICK:** `#clickme`

```
 $('#main').append('<div id="anothermain"><button id="anotherclick"></button></div>');
```

**ON CLICK:** `#clickme2`

```
 $('#main').append('<div id="anothermain4"><button id="anotherclick4"></button></div>');
```

**ON CLICK:** `#anotherclick`

```
 $('#anothermain').append('<div id="anothermain2"><button id="anotherclick2"></button></div>');
```

**ON CLICK:** `#anotherclick2`

```
 $('#main').append('<div id="mainsibling"><button id="clicksibling"></button></div>');
```

**ON CLICK:** `#anotherclick4`

```
 $('#main').append('<div id="anothermain5"><button id="anotherclick2"></button></div>');
```

Above is just an example to show that the click events are huge (350+) and are dynamically created in different parts of site.

So i want to know how to deal with these problems without using delegation to document. ?

*Sometimes Focus on textbox,dropdown click etc are slow to react when there are lots of elements on screen*

Comment: One way would be to get as close to the object as possible: `$("#main").on('click','button',function(){});`

Comment: the only closest thing that can contain all elements is `#main` which is child of document/body so i dont think it will affect much

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to bind the click on the new element after you have created it.

Rather than attaching all the event handlers on page load, you can create the element on click of an existing element, and handle the click on newly clicked element there itself. Something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="main">
   <button id="clickme"></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#clickme").on('click', function(e) {
        var $anotherMain = $('<div id="anothermain"><button id="anotherclick"></button></div>');
        $('#main').append($anotherMain);
        //handle click on anotherMain
        $anotherMain.on('click', function(e) {
            var $anotherMain2 = $('<div id="anothermain2"><button id="anotherclick2"></button></div>');
            $('#main').append($anotherMain2);
            //handle click on anotherMain
            $anotherMain2.on('click', function(e) {
                // add anotherMain3 and so on.
            });
        })
    })
});
```

**Common functionality of creating new elements and binding their clicks can be pulled out and reused.**

Comment: And what if there is branching network of click events. for example. lets say onclick `#clickme2` **a sibling of** `#clickme` appends  `#anotherclick4` which onclick appends  `#anotherclick3` ?  How will i know then if `#anotherclick3` is clicked  ?

Comment: From what I understand the problem is that you don't have the elements on page load hence you need to use delegation. However, you are creating elements dynamically, and at that point, you have the reference to the created element, so, you can bind click on it.